# getcwd second parameter

Tags: c++, getcwd

What should i fill in the second parameter of the function getcwd if I am reading the current directory?

Answer (score 5):

The size of the buffer you want to fill:

```
char result[PATH_MAX];
char *r = getcwd(result, PATH_MAX);
```

Failure to set this correctly (or spot `ENAMETOOLONG`/`ERANGE`) could lead to buffer overflow problems.

Caveat: [Not all platforms provide PATH_MAX](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/community/gsoc/project_ideas/maxpath.html). If you can be sure it's there on your platforms it is quite handy.

You can also use `realpath()`, (POSIX.1-2008) which will `malloc()` memory for you to do this more cleanly:

```
char *result = realpath(".", NULL);
// do stuff with result
free(result);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PATH_MAX-1` to take care of the terminating null character?

Comment: I don't believe so, the manpage states "If the length of the absolute pathname of the current working
       directory, including the terminating null byte, exceeds size
       bytes, NULL is returned,"

Answer (score 2):

The length of the buffer you provide in the first parameter, so that overflow cannot occur.